# Problem with Beginner Tutorials #17

Tags: ros, rosbag, tutorial, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when I try to use the command `rosbag record -a`, it gives me this output:

```
robot@ASHROCK:~/bagfiles$ rosbag record -a /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosbag/record: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosbag.so: undefined symbol:
_ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPN7log4cxx6LoggerENS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS9_S9_z
```

What is this error and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202514/problem-with-beginner-tutorials-#17/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-05**:
Did you install ros desktop full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

was the solution.

---

Originally posted by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) with karma: 82 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-05**:
Please mark your answer as correct.

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-05**:
It says that *>25 points required to accept or unaccept your own answer*

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-06**:
Oh sorry I always forget this restriction. Now you have enough karma.

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-06**:
I hope that this is good karma :)